# Is Point Inside Rounded Rectangle?

Tags: ios, uikit, geometry

I have this code to draw rounded rectangles:

```
void ContextAddRoundedRect(CGContextRef ctx, CGRect rect, CGFloat radius) {
    CGFloat minX = CGRectGetMinX(rect);
    CGFloat maxX = CGRectGetMaxX(rect);
    CGFloat minY = CGRectGetMinY(rect);
    CGFloat maxY = CGRectGetMaxY(rect);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, minX + radius, minY);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(ctx, maxX, minY, maxX, minY + radius, radius);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(ctx, maxX, maxY, maxX - radius, maxY, radius);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(ctx, minX, maxY, minX, maxY - radius, radius);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(ctx, minX, minY, minX + radius, minY, radius);
}
```

how can I figure out if a given CGPoint is inside my rect, **considering the rounded corners?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of building it directly into the `CGContextRef` like this, you can build it instead as a [`UIBezierPath`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html), and then use `-[UIBezierPath containsPoint:]`.

When you're ready to actually render your path into the context, you can do so via:

```
CGContextAddPath(ctx, [myBezierPath CGPath]);
```

Comment: This is great, still looking at UIBezierPath to see if I can do something like `CGContextAddArcToPoint` without having to learn any new geometry.

Comment: @Yar For the things that UIBezierPath doesn't support, you can access it's `CGPath` property, perform the `CGMutablePathRef` operation, and then use `+bezierPathWithCGPath:` to get back to a `UIBezierPath` object.

Comment: @MaxGabriel that's awesome. Could you make that an answer? It's sort of a nice way to keep me from learning new ways of making arcs, which is my number 1 goal.

Also, I'd kind of like to see how much my code changes if I use `CGMutablePathRef` instead of just slamming stuff onto the CGContext.

Comment: I've moved my question on whether there are disadvantages to here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14299140/disadvantages-to-using-cgmutablepathref thanks for all the help!