# Disadvantages to using CGMutablePathRef?

Tags: ios, uikit

I have this code to draw rounded rectangles:

```
void ContextAddRoundedRect(CGContextRef ctx, CGRect rect, CGFloat radius) {
    CGFloat minX = CGRectGetMinX(rect);
    CGFloat maxX = CGRectGetMaxX(rect);
    CGFloat minY = CGRectGetMinY(rect);
    CGFloat maxY = CGRectGetMaxY(rect);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, minX + radius, minY);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(ctx, maxX, minY, maxX, minY + radius, radius);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(ctx, maxX, maxY, maxX - radius, maxY, radius);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(ctx, minX, maxY, minX, maxY - radius, radius);
    CGContextAddArcToPoint(ctx, minX, minY, minX + radius, minY, radius);
}
```

I'm going to convert it to use a `CGMutablePathRef` for the drawing, because then I can use `-[UIBezierPath containsPoint:]` (by using `+bezierPathWithCGPath:` first, as specified in [the comments and answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14298757/8047).)

**Are there are any serious/known disadvantages to using `CGMutablePathRef` as opposed to just drawing directly on the CGContext?** My guess is that it's a non-starter, but maybe there's something I'm missing.

(I know I have to release it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems an ok approach to me... maybe you can even cache it somehow? *I mean don't redo the path every time but only when rect or radius change

*of course a mutable path will have a higher memory footprint but that should be ignorable in this case*

---

e.g.:

```
UIBezierPath *pathWithRoundedRect(NSRect rect, CGFloat radius) {
    CGMutablePathRef path;
    ...

    id p = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithCGPath:path];
    CGPathRelease(path);
    return p;
```

}

Comment: I never draw unless the rect changes. 

My plan is to return a `UIBezierPath` instead of void, though... ugh, I don't know if I have the skills to not create a leak if I do that. Can I just return a `UIBezierPath` from this straight C function?

Comment: I would make your function do one or the other... either draw the path, or create the path and return it. If you choose to create the path, rename your function to `CGPathCreateRoundedRect()`, for example. In this case, the _caller_ would be responsible for calling `CGPathRelease()`, or the path would never be cleaned up. (By convention, calling a function/method with "create" in its name returns a reference that the caller owns and must release)

Comment: Finally, if you are just drawing this path, you can use a `CAShapeLayer`, which I believe will be faster than drawing the path in your context... depends how often you are drawing.

Comment: just return a UIBezierPath and release the CGPath and you're good :) added. some sample code. But what nielsbot says in its comment also makes sense

Comment: cool and then the client can use `CGContextAddPath(ctx, [result CGPath]);` where the result is what's gotten back from that function. @nielsbot thank you, I'll  look into the use of `CAShapeLayer` and point taken about the name of the function.

Answer (score 3):

Just use [`+[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:cornerRadius:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIBezierPath/bezierPathWithRoundedRect%3acornerRadius%3a) and save yourself all the trouble. If you really need a `CGPathRef` from it, then get the [`CGPath`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBezierPath_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIBezierPath/CGPath) property.

Unless you do this thousands of times per second, it's unlikely to be noticeably slow or take a significant amount of memory.

Comment: Thanks Kurt. I hadn't noticed that method. Great stuff.

Answer (score 1):

No, `CGContext` has an internal path, the functions on `CGContext` to draw, are just calling the equivalent functions on its internal `CGMutablePath`. There's no reason to not make the CGMutablePath yourself, the path functions on `CGContext` are a convenience.

If you're not going to draw the path using the `CGContext` then you're better to make a `CGMutablePath`.